# Update using joins to fill in missing values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have written these lines to fill in the null values in the *zip code* column. It is supposed to fill in the *zip code* column based on the value of the *location* column.

When I execute it, it keeps running indefinitely and doesn't give me the desired result. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or what other method can I use to get the desired result?

```
UPDATE nycaccidents2020 a
JOIN nycaccidents2020 b
    USING(location)
SET a.`zip code` = b.`zip code`
WHERE a.`zip code` IS NULL AND b.`zip code` IS NOT NULL;
```

Sample table:

| location | zip code |
| --- | --- |
| POINT (-73.946556 40.8165) | 10030 |
| POINT (-73.83376 40.8921) | 10466 |
| POINT (-73.919914 40.6905) | 11221 |
| POINT (-73.946556 40.8165) | null |

Comment: Your current sql doesn't make sense. How would it know WHICH zip code to put in the null value.

Comment: I am unsure how the two tables a and b differ. To me it seems like you are joining the table with itself? Then where are you getting the additional information from that you are looking for? Could you provide further details on which tables you have and what their contents look like?

Comment: You need to provide an example of the desired result. In the last row, the zip code is null, what should show instead of the null?

Comment: @JohnL It's presumably supposed to copy the zip code from the first row, which has the same location.

Comment: @Barmar Ah i see, in that case one of the tables needs to be deduped and nulls removed, then it can be the master for zip code to location lookup

Answer (score 1):

The query is technically correct, but it may be slow because there are many rows with the same location, and it's joining with all of them, resulting in a large cross product. You can improve it by joining with a subquery that reduces them to one row per location.

```
UPDATE nycaccidents2020 AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT location, `zip code`
    FROM nyaccidents2020
    WHERE `zip code` IS NOT NULL
) AS b USING (location)
SET a.`zip code` = b.`zip code`
WHERE a.`zip code` IS NULL
```

This might also have performance problems because the subquery isn't indexed. You can improve it by creating a temporary table and indexing it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE locations AS
    SELECT DISTINCT location, `zip code`
    FROM nyaccidents2020
    WHERE `zip code` IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE locations ADD INDEX (location);

UPDATE nycaccidents2020 a
JOIN locations b USING(location)
SET a.`zip code` = b.`zip code`
WHERE a.`zip code` IS NULL
```

This whole problem could be avoided by normalizing your data. You can have a separate table with locations and zip codes, and the accidents tables can use a foreign key that references this table.

Comment: thanks! I'll make a separate table for these columns

Answer (score 0):

The query will join all Rows, so it would be ebetter id you had an id filed so you could make  a.id < b.id, like when you try to find doubles.

But you can try, this wiuld select only one row from all rows with a zip code for a specific location and so would join only once instead as you query does with all existing rows in your table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE nycaccidents2020 
>     (`location` GEOMETRY, `zip code` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO nycaccidents2020 
>     (`location`, `zip code`)
> VALUES
>     ('POINT (-73.946556 40.8165)', '10030'),
>     ('POINT (-73.83376 40.8921)', '10466'),
>     ('POINT (-73.919914 40.6905)', '11221'),
>     ('POINT (-73.946556 40.8165)', NULL)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE nycaccidents2020  t1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `location`, MIN(`zip code`) as `zip code` FROM nycaccidents2020 WHERE `zip code` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `location` )  t2 ON t1.`location` = t2.`location` AND t1.`zip code` IS NULL AND t1.`zip code` <=> t2.`zip code`
> SET t1.`zip code` = t2.`zip code`
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff18fd71320860be66ca3217c462e3d4)*fiddle=df5a70b8f77372dcf9d03b54caa5f7e4)*